# Is there a way to fix Angular CLI generated files to stop appearing Red in WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

Is there a way to fix Angular CLI generated files to stop appearing Red in WebStorm?

It's getting kind of annoying, whenever I use the CLI to generate a file it appears red and there used to be  an error in the Console but it goes away.

Image for reference :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your `tslint.json` file and set your rules to match the Angular CLI defaults. Let's say CLI generated files with double quotes but you have a single quote in `tslint.json`.

```
{
    "extends": "../tslint.json",
    "rules": {
        "directive-selector": [
            true,
            "attribute",
            "app",
            "camelCase"
        ],
        "component-selector": [
            true,
            "element",
            "app",
            "kebab-case"
        ]
    }
}
```

Use this default, and might solve the problem:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/tslint.json

This might also help to change inspection preference:
[image: Webstorm Preferences]

If that's because of version control, fix it from preferences:
[image]

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeDufour Webstorm also has options for controlling the color of files for version control.

Comment: Looking into that right now. I'll spend some time figuring out the right configurations for me. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR : Webstorm automaticly register your folder as if using source control even if not setted up. Go to File > Settings > Version Control and remove Git next to directory.

Thanks you for answering so quickly and trying to help me @Maihan Nijat . These solutions did not work because it actually had nothing to do with Typescript errors. The red marked files (all newly created ones), in this case, meant that they were not commited to source control even if I am not currently using any. By default, Angular CLI seems to be doing that for you when you generate a new projet and even if you don't enter your Github informations Webstorm reacts as if you were using it. I went to File > Settings > Version Control and removed Git next to directory.

I might aswell start using it to keep track.